# Swift: Using an enum to represent the rank of Playing Cards

Tags: ios, swift, enums, switch-statement, case

I am trying to make an enum to express the rank of Playing Cards, as per the following specs:

The Rank enum should only have three cases: `.ace`, `.numeric` and `.face`.  `.ace` represents an Ace, `.numeric` represents a number card, and `.face` represents a face card as JQK.

We also want to have a variable `order` to return the rank of the integer for printing (for example, a "Q" would return 12.

The enum produce the following:

```
var a = Rank.ace
var b = Rank.numeric(pipsCount: 7)
var c = Rank.face("Q")
print("\(a.order)") \\prints: 1
print("\(b.order)") \\prints: 7
print("\(c.order)") \\prints: 12
```

So far my problem is with getting it to print 12 for "Q".

I used:

```
    case ace
    case numeric(pipsCount: Int)
    case face(String)
```

To make the cases

And then a switch to make the other stuff

```
          switch self {
          case .ace:
               return 1
          case .numeric(let pipsCount):
            return pipsCount
          case .face
               return 0
        }
```

But I'm just not sure how to set up `care .face` because I'm not sure how do i convert the input from JQK into 11, 12, and 13 respectively?

Comment: you can give it any name .. it will accept that

Answer (score 4):

Since you didn't name the associated value explicitly you can extract it using any name you like. In this example I chose `id`:

```
enum Rank {
    case ace
    case numeric(pipsCount: Int)
    case face(String)

    var order: Int {
        switch self {
        case .ace:
            return 1
        case .numeric(let pipsCount):
            return pipsCount
        case .face(let id):
            switch id {
            case "J":
                return 11
            case "Q":
                return 12
            case "K":
                return 13
            default:
                return 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm kinda new to swift and didn't realize you could name the parameter on the fly.